# GitHub: Is it possible to have a repository out of repositories?

Tags: git, symfony, github

I store my php projects under an private GitHub account.

Now for example I have different components (news bundle, user bundle, etc.) and one project which uses all them together (e.g. custom website). Can I somehow symlink them?

Or should I only use component repositories?

Regards

EDIT:

There most be an easy way to do this for example for the symfony2 project.
There are always the components which are also available in the parent repository.

For example: https://github.com/symfony/OptionsResolver

symfony/OptionsResolver->syfmony/symfony->symfony/standard-edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I handle dependencies in Symfony 2 Git projects is this:

The main project is under Git. External dependencies (Bundles and all that vendor stuff) go into the .deps file (or composer.json). Then I either run `php bin/vendors install` or `composer install` to install the dependencies.

The dependencies will be installed as Git repositories, so, if I wanted to, I could `cd` into them and commit there and push it if I have rights. This makes editing of your own bundles easier, no need to clone a separate bundle repo just to be able to make changes there.

I also have this structure:

```
src\Company\SharedBundle
src\Company\ProjectBundle
```

Where `SharedBundle` is simply specified as a dependency and the target installation path is under `src\Company`.

I am using the `SharedBundle` in all of my projects. If I need to make changes to it, I do them in one of the projects, then I `cd src\Company\SharedBundle`, commit to it and push it, and pull from all projects that use it when I need the changes.

With `deps`, you can do targeting like:

```
[AcmeAwesomeBundle]
    git=http://github.com/johndoe/Acme/AwesomeBundle.git
    target=../src/Acme/AwesomeBundle
```

If you use Composer, you probably want this: http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Hi, this is what I was searching for! But there are still some questions: 1. So when I cd into the root of an sub git project git automaticly changes the repository (for push, etc.). Nothing more to do? 2. Where do you set the target dir of the git dependencies (I assume that the bundle gets registered in the main composer.json and the dir gets set in the composer.json of the bundle, but how do I directly set the extraction dir?)

Comment: @user1246987 1) Yes, for the second answer, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly I fail at the composer part. What steps are required to install a private package into /src by composer? EDIT: However when I create the git repository manuelly and use it with the IDE it works quite good. No really need for composer.. The only thing what could be better is that the main project should als view the components. At the moment there is only a sign that the subdirectories belong to another repo

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Submodules.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Is this the only solution? The symfony2 project uses often hierarchical repositories. Any idea how they handle this? https://github.com/symfony/OptionsResolver
Also submodules aren't easy to handle

Answer (score 1):

You can use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to handle dependencies. This won't lock subprojects to a specific commit like submodules do. Symfony uses composer.

Comment: Hi, I use composer myself (master branch). The question is how I could handle different git's in one project like symfony does. So for example I have the whole project as repository and the stand alone bundles as repository. What do I have to do to handle this with git?

Comment: above the symfony2 components in github there is following notice:[READ-ONLY] Subtree split of the Symfony Twig Bundle -- clone into Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle (master at symfony/symfony)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to import all the files from various different repositories into one other repository, and be able to update them as needed, I believe you can simply add all the other repositories to the main one as remote repositories.

Obviously, back everything up before trying this, but I think you simply want to use "git remote add [arbitrary name of other repository] [location of other repository]", "git fetch [arbitrary name of other repository]" and "get merge [arbitrary name of other repository]/[branch of other repository]".  You can do this with as many different repositories as you like.  For instance, all my repositories now start off as clones of the repository for the framework they're built with.  It doesn't matter one bit that my projects don't really have anything to do with the framework except they happen to use it as a starting point.

So you'd want something like this:

```
git remote add news-bundle git://example.com/news-bundle.git
git merge news-bundle/master
git remote add user-bundle git://example.com/user-bundle.git
git merge user-bundle/master
```

Then, when you've made more changes to news-bundle, you can update the other repository like this:

```
git fetch news-bundle
git merge news-bundle/master
```